# How to get Human-like mouse clicks in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, anti-bot

I want to login into a page which has an antibot, that tracks your mouse movement and decides based on that mouse movement, if you are or if you are not a bot.

My question is, is it possible in selenium, to make such human like mouse clicks on some specific parts of the website? I heard of 'Ghost-Cursor' but I think this only works in Puppeteer. Otherwise I could use Pyautogui, but then I would have to let the browser-window opened all the time. And with Pyautogui I would be limited and could not run multiple test at the same time.

PS: I've found that I have to click on parts of the website, that I can interact with, such as an input window.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Please, share